# Conemu Environment settings not being used / overridden

Tags: windows, environment-variables, conemu, alias

Using Conemu (latest stable) on Windows 7, and populating the environment settings with lots of handy aliases, among other things.  Now when I start ConEmu64.exe directly, somehow it ignores the settings stored in its xml file and uses other settings instead.  What could be causing that, or rather, where might it be getting these other overriding settings from?

Comment: Unless you tell us what "other settings" do you mean nobody can answer you.

Comment: No, I'm saying that Conemu is just quietly grabbing a different set of environment settings, including a couple of aliases that I never set, and ignoring what I have specified in the Environments tab.  It's like it's reading a .bashrc file from somewhere else, I just can't figure out where/what it is.

Comment: ConEmu environment page states that aliases are set up for cmd.exe. Also, ConEmu never manages any of .bashrc files. Moreover if you are talking about WSL, its environment can't be configured through ConEmu at all.